# Complexity of insertObject:atIndex:

Tags: objective-c, time-complexity

What is the complexity of `-[NSArray insertObject:atIndex:]` -- `N`? or constant?

Also, how can I find out the complexity of various Objective-C statements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [discussion here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSMutableArray) and CFArray.h source code states:

> Computational Complexity
>   The access time for a value in the array is
>   guaranteed to be at   worst O(lg N) for any implementation, current and
>   future, but will  often be O(1) (constant time). Linear search
>   operations similarly  have a worst case complexity of O(N*lg N),
>   though typically the  bounds will be tighter, and so on. Insertion or
>   deletion operations   will typically be linear in the number of values
>   in the array, but     may be O(N*lg N) clearly in the worst case in some
>   implementations.  There are no favored positions within the array for
>   performance;  that is, it is not necessarily faster to access values
>   with low  indices, or to insert or delete values with high indices, or
>     whatever.

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly, the performance of arrays in Foundation [depends on the size of the array](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/).

I don't think there's any site that spells out the performance of all the data structures in 
Foundation, but the linked article gives a nice observational analysis that you could repeat for other containers such as NSMutableDictionary.

Answer (score 3):

there really is no matrix (afaik), but this post should help explain *why* as well as answer the question in the subject:

http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Just a nit pick: `NSArray` or `CFArray` is not a part of the language, it’s a Core Foundation class. You can take a look at [CFArray source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.15/CFArray.c) to reason about its complexity, but it looks like it would take a while :) If you are concerned about real-world performance (as opposed to  asking from a theoretical point of view), do a test and profile.

Answer (score 0):

The official documents don't state it, but I guess it is similar to array lists in other languages, which would be O(n).

Comment: Interestingly, ([as Manny noted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329761/what-is-the-complexity-of-insertobjectatindex/7329918#7329918)) the CFArray header gives some performance details, and it performs more like a hash table: O(log N) at worst for access.

Comment: @Josh: yes, I noticed. Looking at CFArray.c, it seems to be a rather complex type (although I have no idea why it must be so complicated).