# What's the complexity of containsObject in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarray, contains

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html

Is it O(n) or O(log n)

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complexity of insertObject:atIndex:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329761/complexity-of-insertobjectatindex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation you linked to answers the question:

> This method determines whether *anObject* is present in the array by sending an `isEqual:` message to each of the array’s objects (and passing *anObject* as the parameter to each `isEqual:` message).

So `containsObject` iterates over each of the array's objects, which is an O(n) operation. (Presumably the algorithm stops if it finds a match, so it would test n / 2 objects on average.)

Comment: It's O(n) in the common private backing subclasses, and guaranteed to be O(n log n) or better in all of them.